# 'Play to' feature on Windows 7: how to support more formats?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, dlna

So, I can use 'Play to' on **.m2ts** (presumable decoded) or **.avi** to send it to smart tv; guessing it's done with Windows Media Player.

However, I want to support **.mkv** playback out of the box; what should be installed make Windows to support more formats for 'Play to'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know, it is not possible :( Even if you install the appropriate codecs for Windows Media Player, it will play MKV fine, but still can't play them with "Play to". It seems, it can "play to" to natively supported formats only. Here are the table of the supported formats:

[image]

As you can see, m2ts and avi are there, but no MKV...

Answer (score 0):

Its a hack but you can rename the .mkv file as .wmv and the use playto.